# How can I save to text g++ or gcc compiler status in C++?

Tags: c++, cmd

I want to save to a text file the C++ compiler status. I'm using Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "C++ compiler status". If you want to save what the compiler prints on the screen, just redirect it to a file: g++ -c file.cpp > compileroutput.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redirect the output to a file using the redirection operator '>'. 
You may want to use the STDERR stream for redirection as most of the compilers output the compilation errors on this stream, so you should try the '2>' redirection.

refer the below link for more details on redirection on Windows:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx